# Can anyone recommend a good java lib to introspect video?

Tags: java, video

I need to get the aspect ratio from a multitude of video formats (flv, wmv, mp4, mov, etc). What would you guys recommend as a relatively slim JAR that has the tools to inspect the video's header and get this data out. I don't need anything too beefy as this is the sole operation that it's going to perform.

FFMPEG is not an option, btw.... so... I need other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes into my mind is the [Java Media Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/), but I admit, I don't know where to look for metadata info within the framework.

The [Wotsit](http://www.wotsit.org/) site has links to various video format descriptions - if you want to do it yourself.

There is also an open source C++ media analyzer called [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net). If you can read C++ code you can recognize how it reads metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) to get information about video files, and to decode and encode them to and from raw images and audio if you want.